# Accessing fields with '@' symbol of object in dGrid

Tags: javascript, json, dgrid

I have an issue to set fields of layer in dGrid.

```
store = new Memory({data: someData});
grid = new Grid({
    store: store
});

layout = {[label: 'ID', field: '@attributes', formatter: getId]};

grid.set('columns', layout);
```

the someData is an object with the following structure

```
someData = {
{@attributes: {
    id: someId
}},
{@attributes: {
    id: someId
}},
};

getId = function (value, rowId) {
return value.id;
};
```

well, it cannot get the Id or anything.

I appreciate any suggestion. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried quoting the field name: `someData = {'@attributes': {id: someId}};`?

Comment: @Thilo I don't really have a control at the data since it is received as JSON object from outside of the server.

Comment: What's `getId`? A function you made? Part of dgrid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was pretty simple, as you guys would already know, to access an object with @ symbol you need bracket notation. Since `dGrid` supports `formatter` you can achieve the task by doing like this

```
layout = {[
    label: 'ID', field: '@attributes', formatter: function (value) {
        return value['@attributes'].id;}
]};
```

And that will display ID value in `@attributes`.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously can't access it using dot notation. You will have to use square bracket notation.

```
someData['@attributes'].id
```

It's unclear if `getId` is something you created or part of dgrid and you aren't able to change it. If the latter, you should rename the `@attributes` property after you've accessed it but before you send it to dgrid.

```
someData.attributes = someData['@attributes'];
delete someData['@attributes'];
// send it off to dgrid...
```

Comment: getId is what I created to make use of formatter to do the similar thing with your answer. but it turns out dgrid can't pass the '@attributes' to the method. One more thing I was unclear about is someData contains array of objects not just a single array. so changing the name of property doesn't seem like what I am looking for. Cheers.